# FOS REST Bundle: funny thing with a "persons" resource

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOS Rest bundle to create a REST resource for a "persons" resource, basically the urls are meant to be:

- List: GET /api/persons
- Add: POST /api/persons
- Get single person: GET /api/persons/{id}
- Modify: PUT /api/persons/{id}
- Delete: DELETE /api/persons/{id}

So I defined my methods in the controllers as follows:

```
public function cgetPersonsAction() # List
public function cgetPersonAction(...) # Get single
public function cdeletePersonAction(...) # Delete
#etc...
```

And here comes the funny part, instead of /api/persons for get single, put, post and delete FOS Rest bundle calculates the plural of person into people instead of persons and the urls ended up being:

- List: GET /api/persons
- Add: POST /api/people
- Get single person: GET /api/people/{id}
- Modify: PUT /api/people/{id}
- Delete: DELETE /api/people/{id}

I searched the code looking for maybe some people/person in the bundle but I found nothing, so I guess it must be related with some php plural function.

Do you know if there's any way to force the url to remain being "person"? I think people doesn't make too much sense here

Comment: have a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html#changing-pluralization-in-generated-routes) - routes are getting pluralized by default, so that's probably your "issue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the url by using:

```
FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get; ...\Post; ,...
```

For GET url it would be:

```
@Get("api/whatever/{id}")
```